# How to reverse increase or decrease Html5 number spinner?

Tags: html, numbers, spinner, reverse

I have one field in my form priority field that submits itself `onchange`.

I would like to reverse the direction of the spinner control. So, if they press the up arrow it decreases instead of increasing the field value. And if they press the down arrow it increases instead of decrease the field value.

I have tried making `step= '-1'` but it's not allowed according to the html5 docs and does not work.

```
<input type="number" name="priority" value='5' onClick="this.select();"  min="1" step="1" max="10" onChange="javascript:submitForm('frm_tosubmit')" required="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

If jQuery UI is an option, its [Spinner](https://jqueryui.com/spinner/) class supports negative steps.

```js
$("#input").spinner({
  step: -1,
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<label>jQuery UI <input id="input" value="5"></label>
<br>
<label>HTML5 number <input type="number" value="5"></label>
```

Though I still would like to see a solution without jQuery UI.